# Custom option for each quantity item for team tshirt selling

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a magento e-commerce website which sells t-shirts fro team or company. For each t-shirt we provide different color, sizes, neck-design etc., which is fine and I can easily achieve it using configurable products and custom options in magento.

Also, we want to provide two more options, front-text and back-number. Say some company wants to order 100 t-shirts for thier employees, with "ABC Company" written on front and number between 1 to 100 written on back side of t-shirts.

So, if customer ordering 100 qty, then I want to one main textbox which will have main company name, and also textbox against each qty so that they can modify the text or number for any tshirt they want. I am not able to understand how should I do this in magento.

I found a website which does the same: http://www.tshirtexpert.co.uk/tshirt-printing/Stag/LEFT_CHEST_STAG_%5Bstag%5D.aspx When you go to this link, choose options and click next, then you will see text option for each quantity.

Please check and advise if this is possible in magento? or if not, should I look for custom solution or any other CMS such as woocomerce can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, the [webpage](http://www.tshirtexpert.co.uk/tshirt-printing/Stag/LEFT_CHEST_STAG_[stag].aspx) you've linked is created using ASP.NET AJAX framework
- If you want a similar kind of feature, then you can use AJAX with default magento.
- The logic will be as follows:
- Customer gives input to qty field in product view page
- In background the AJAX will take the qty input and will place a form window below the qty depending on your theme
- User will give the input(front name, back no.) for every t-shirt
- You need to store this info with the product details in order in a separate table or attribute for future reference as well as delivery options
- That's it

Comment: Hi Rahul, I know that logic, but I was searching if we have any pre-made plugin or solution for this. But I don't think there is any such solution, I might need to develop it using custom code I guess.

Comment: Hello Prashant, yes, you're right. There's no exact extension is available as per your need. A customization will definitely serve the purpose.